# POP3/IMAP/SMTP client for asp.net MVC

Tags: .net, email, smtp, imap, pop3

Is there any POP3/SMTP/IMAP Client for asp.net mvc4? 
Should support 
         1) Retrieve email in Inbox, Draft and Send separately. 
         2) Send eMail with attachment.
         3) Download multiple attachment in an email as zip or individually.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You're asking for opinions, which is not the stackoverflow way. Moreover, if you were to browse the .net/imap questions you'd find the answers PDQ anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use MailKit from source at my [GitHub](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) or via easy-to-install packages from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit)